# Can somebody explain the naming convention behind the standard Jetty logs?

Tags: logging, jetty

When I look in our Jetty logs folder (/opt/jetty/logs for us) I see the following "built in" log files..

A sequence of files like this...

1. 2012_11_16.stderrout.log
2. 2012_11_16.stderrout.log.231810595
3. 2012_11_16.stderrout.log.232105322
4. 2012_11_16.stderrout.log.234629703

and

RPActivityLog.txt

and

start.log

First what is the difference between stderrout, RpActivyLog (is this standard?), and start.log.  Finally what do the numbers after log.xxxxxx mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well jetty writes `stderroout.log` based on the configuration which given under `/etc/jetty-loggin.xml`

```
  <New id="ServerLog" class="java.io.PrintStream">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
      <Arg><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.stderrout.log</Arg>
      <Arg type="boolean">false</Arg>
      <Arg type="int">1</Arg>
      <Arg><Call class="java.util.TimeZone" name="getTimeZone"><Arg>GMT</Arg></Call></Arg>
      <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
```

- `RpActivyLog` is not standard one, probably written by your webapp.
- If you are using `--daemon`, stderr and stdout redirected to `${jetty.log}/start.log`
- log.xxxx means if you restart jetty often, old log files may be renamed with some random numbers.

See [Jetty/Feature/Jetty Logging](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Logging) for more reference.

Comment: LOL I didn't realize log.xxxx was just random stuff appended if/when you restart.

Comment: @Benju Its not time stamp, if you know the answer, update it pl.

Comment: Not sure what it means either.